# How to get strategy.opentrades.entry_price for a Tradingview indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy that works and I would like to make it an indicator.
I still have one line of code to transform to make my indicator valid but I can't do it.

```
entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an entry condition called `entry_cond`.

Use a `var` to store the entry price whenever your `entry_cond` becomes `true`.

```
var float entry_price = na
entry_price := entry_cond ? close : entry_price  // If it is a new entry, store the close price. Else, keep the old value
```

Two notes:

1. You have to make sure that `entry_cond` only becomes `true` when you enter a new trade
2. You should write `na` into `entry_price` when you exit a trade.